# PHP Mail(): Setting Return Path Fails Mail Sending

Tags: php, email, return-path

I am sending email using PHP's `mail()` function. However, when I set the ReturnPath header like '`-femail@domain.com`', however the email fails with the return path 5th parameter but when not used, `anonymous@default.com` return path is added. Is this an error and how do we get around to using specific return path.

Kind regards,

Khuram

Comment: some sendmail configs do not allow the change of the returnPath , you might whant to look there too .

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you're using Sendmail with `root` access to the server:**

I've tested the result on my server where Sendmail is basically in it's factory configuration:

```
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@address');
```

When using -f, Sendmail must know that you are a trusted user. You must add the server user to `/etc/mail/trusted-users`. For example, if the web server user is `apache` or `www-data`, you must put that into the `trusted-users` file.

Once you've done this, you probably have to enable the feature. Edit `/etc/mail/submit.mc` and add the following line *properly*:

```
FEATURE('use_ct_file')dnl
```

Once you're done `service sendmail restart` should do the job.